# H1 Not Centering

Tags: html, css

My H1 is not centering as I increase the font, if I have a smaller size (30px) font my H1 positions correctly. **[I want my H1 to be in the center of my banner div and look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LhkV.png)** Currently my H1 is too low from the center and text-align:center; is not solving this issue. What do I need to add or remove to make my H1 center or do I need to remove or add something to my banner?

[Jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cu4h3j8t/4/)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.banner {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #8F3144;
  height: 300px;
  top: 0px;
}


/* LOGO START*/

.banner>img {
  float: left;
  height: 103px;
  width: 140px;
  color: black;
}


/* LOGO END */

.mainh1 {
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 80px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.nav {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.nav>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.nav>li>a:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" />
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="meetsli"><a href="#">Meets</a></li>
    <li class="aboutli"><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
  </ul>
  <h1 class="mainh1">Harrison TEST TEST TEST TEST</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `padding-top: 80px;` ?

Comment: http://howtocenterincss.com/

Comment: even with removing padding top, my h1 is still not centered in the middle and I'm unsure what to do

Comment: I dont understand why I'm getting downvoted I have no idea what to do and new to html/css

Comment: You're probably getting downvotes as you've not explain what you're trying to achieve clearly.  `text-align:center` is for *horizontal* alignment, (which appears to work fine) but you complain it's "too low" - which is *vertical alignment* - so we're not sure if you can't get it to centre (horizontal) or if it's a vertical issue.

Comment: Try adding `line-height:100px;` (or double your `font-size`) https://jsfiddle.net/cu4h3j8t/33/

Comment: codesnippet runs h1 as centered for me?

Answer (score 1):

```
clear: both
```

This is the answer I believe. Add this style to your `h1` tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the size and position of the logo.  You could use `absolute` positioning on the `h1` with `width: 100%` and remove the `padding`.  See the snippet:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.banner {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #8F3144;
  height: 300px;
  top: 0px;
}


/* LOGO START*/

.banner>img {
  float: left;
  height: 103px;
  width: 140px;
  color: black;
}


/* LOGO END */

.mainh1 {
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.nav>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.nav>li>a:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" />
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="meetsli"><a href="#">Meets</a></li>
    <li class="aboutli"><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
  </ul>
  <h1 class="mainh1">Harrison TEST TEST TEST TEST</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the following two properties to the mainh.

```
  margin-top:auto;
  margin-botton:auto;
```

This should solve the problem and keep it always centered, although it goes off screen at that big of fonts.

Also you can try placing it in a `<center>` tag